# How do I properly check that a istreambuf_iterator has reached end-of-stream

Tags: c++

In the standard I read that you have to create a deafult iterator to be able to know if the iterator has reach end-of stream. I think it's getting quite ugly, isn't there any predefined symbol or equivalent that could help us here?

> The default-constructed std::istreambuf_iterator is known as the end-of-stream iterator. When a valid std::istreambuf_iterator reaches the end of the underlying stream, it becomes equal to the end-of-stream iterator.

Here is code example:

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(is);
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;

    if (it != end) { break;}
```

Why doesn't the iterator has a function named, i.e. hasNext() or isEndOfStream()

Comment: I think you answered the question in the title yourself. As to the second question, it is about presenting a uniform interface across all iterators. And not all iterators can know, within themselves, when they reached the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> isn't there any predefined symbol or equivalent that could help us here?

Yes.

> you have to create a deafult iterator to be able to know if the iterator has reach end-of stream

Here it is!

> Why doesn't the iterator has a function named, i.e. hasNext() or isEndOfStream()

The singular iterator as sentinel is actually quite elegant. It doesn't introduce any new names into the library, and it allows us to write generic code with `start` and `end` iterators that doesn't care what kind of thing you're iterating over. That's really important for the standard algorithms.

```
void bar(const char c);

template <typename Iterator>
void foo(Iterator start, Iterator end)
{
   for (Iterator it = start; it != end; ++it)
      bar(*it);
}

void version_1()
{
   std::istreambuf_iterator<char> start(std::cin);
   std::istreambuf_iterator<char> end;
   foo(start, end);
}

void version_2()
{
   std::vector<char> v{0,1,2,3,4,5};
   foo(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Imagine if for containers you had `start` and `end`, but for streams you had `start` and a call to `start.hasNext()`? Now, that's not very elegant. *That's* messy!

Comment: In version_2 I can see the benefit, the solution is appealing. Maybe I'm just picky, but  in version_1 you declare the end variable as described in the standard, which I don't like to have to do. In most cases you want to iterate over the complete set, so why do you have to add the "end" if the end is always the end. (hope that makes sense)

Comment: @JohanEngblom: I addressed that. It's so you can write generic code. It's not that big a deal to construct `end`, surely? It's worth it for changing "all cases" to "most cases" so you can do more things. The C++ standard library is all about flexibility, not prescriptivism.